# Error in menus in Java FX

Tags: javafx-2

I am new to JavaFX using Netbeans 7.3.1 and currently working with Menus. I am reading the book "java Fx 2.0 Introduction by example" and was trying out the menu example in the book when i faced the following error..

constructor Menu in class Menu cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found: String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Here is my code, it is correct as far as my JavaFx knowledge is concerned and have included all major java FX Menu imports!! I dunno why the "Menu" constructor won't take in string as parameters!! Please help!!

```
package menu;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.SeparatorMenuItem;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
public class Menu extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
        Menu menu = new Menu("File");//This line is giving errors..
        menu.getItems().add(new MenuItem("New"));
        menu.getItems().add(new MenuItem("Save"));
        menu.getItems().add(new SeparatorMenuItem());
        menu.getItems().add(new MenuItem("Exit"));
        menuBar.getMenus().add(menu);
        root.getChildren().add(menuBar);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Uluk's answer is correct but I would strongly consider changing the name of this class from Menu to something more specific. At the very least, something that isn't already a core class name.

Comment: You should avoid using names for classes that are already defined as standard classes by JavaFX. The problem was a name collision.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Menu you are instantiating is

```
menu.Menu  // which extends javafx.​application.Application and defined by you, i.e. it is
menu.Menu menu = new menu.Menu("File");
```

Instead specify the full path of JavaFX Menu:

```
javafx.scene.control.Menu menu = new javafx.scene.control.Menu("File");
```

Or give your Menu different name. Ex: MyAwesomeMenu :).

Comment: Thanks ur idea worked!!Uluk!! By the way, i still don't know why that worked and why mine didn't..I have included javafx.scene.control import earlier!!Why do i need to include it again in my code is beyond me!!

Comment: @AnkurSaha. No you didn't import javafx.scene.control.Menu, see your code in the question. There was a class name collision, one is JavaFX class **Menu**, another with the same name is your application's main class **Menu**. Since you didn't import the JavaFX Menu, and your Menu class don't need to be imported because it is in its own class definition, the instantiated Menu treated as the menu which you created and defined in a package menu. The best solution will be changing the name of your class, to specific one.